# how to upload postgresSQL DB in hostinger VPS?

Tags: postgresql, vps

I have taken a VPS Account in hostinger and uploaded my laravel application there and now i want to upload my database made in postgresSQL.

i try to add using create database but it is creating mysql db. and expected to create postgresSQL DB.